# A full wave rectifier with resistive load is a linear load or non-linear load?

Tags: linear

we know if the applied voltage across a load is sinusoidal and also the current drawn is also sinusoidal then we can say that the load is linear load.But we also know that diode is a non-linear device. in case of full wave rectifier with pure resistive load the both applied voltage and current waveforms are sinusoidal, then can we say that the full wave rectifier with resistive load is a linear load?

Answer (score 1):

If you have ideal perfect diodes then you could make a good argument to say it was a linear load. Real world limitations means it's not a linear load especially when the AC voltage applied is small.